# Couldn't load mupdf: findLibrary returned null

Tags: android, mupdf

I have an issue to import mupdf library into my android application. The problem is that the program was running well last week, and I probably changed something in the code that don't load mupdf anymore. If I try to load a pdf file, I have a message with "-my application- has stopped". Here is the logcat error message :

```
2530-2530/com.efc.efcredader E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at com.artifex.mupdfdemo.MuPDFActivity.openFile(MuPDFActivity.java:944)
        at com.artifex.mupdfdemo.MuPDFActivity.onCreate(MuPDFActivity.java:710)
        [...]
 Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load mupdf: findLibrary returned null
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:365)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:535)
        at com.artifex.mupdfdemo.MuPDFCore.<clinit>(MuPDFCore.java:16)
        [...]
```

I call the libmupdf.so like that :

```
static {
    System.loadLibrary("mupdf");
}
```

I've followed a lot a tutorials about how to build mupdf as a library and import it but no one works well (at least for me). So I suppose (and I hope), I'm doing something wrong during the manipulation.
After I imported the "Android" module from mupdf, the folder is like that :

```
>android
    >manifests
        Android.Manifest.xml
  >java
      >com.artifex.mupdfdemo
          All java files
  >res
      >animator
          Xml files
      >drawable
          Xml files
      >layout
          Xml files
      >values
          Xml files
  >c
      Android.mk
      Application.mk
      Core.mk
      libmupdf.so
      mupdf.c
      ThirdParty.mk
```

Even if I try to compile it alone, I have some errors too :

```
make.exe:***No rule to make target ...
```

and

```
Execution failed for task ':android:compileDebugNdk'.
com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\android-ndk-r10d\ndk-build.cmd'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
```

Here is the project's build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'android'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile project(':appcompat_v7')
    compile project(':android-support-v4-preferencefragment-master')
    compile project(':android-support-v7-gridlayout')
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.1"
    compileOptions.encoding = 'ISO-8859-1'

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }
        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
    }
}
```

android's build.gradle :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 16
    buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"

    defaultConfig {
        //applicationId "com.artifex.mupdfdemo"
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 16

        ndk {
            moduleName "mupdf"
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}
```

local.properties

```
sdk.dir=C\:\\Android\\SDK
ndk.dir=C\:\\android-ndk-r10d
```

I'm using Android Studio and the SDK is up to date.

I really don't know how to solve that right now, I would be glad If you have any advice that can help me. If you need any other details or files to add, just ask.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

My solution is:

I'm having the .so files in lib/armeabi and lib/armeabi-v7a, and in the build.gradle I added `jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']` to the existing sourcesets. Hope that is helping you!